# Domain Name Sharing

Tags: tomcat, ssl, iis, https, shared-hosting

How to share a domain name among a .NET application hosted in IIS Server (SSL enabled with port 443) and a Java application hosted in Tomcat server (SSL enabled with port 8443)  while both are running in the same machine?

Comment: Those are distinct ports, so they don't conflict. What is the problem you have while trying this?

Comment: What is the way to achieve this? I found while googling on this, that we can use nginx for reverse proxy but cannot get a clear picture on how to do it. It will be helpful if I can get any link or guidance for it.

Comment: Does it work for you to access the Tomcat as `https://domain.name:8443/` and the IIS as `https://domain.name/`?

Comment: Yeah exactly. But generally wifi and proxy servers in corporate may block https requests on port 8443. So is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: You should add that to your question and the tag `reverse-proxy`. Yes a reverse proxy can forward requests based e.g. on the path from the request URL. Some say IIS supports doing that, but I have no idea about IIS. I know for certain that Nginx, Varnish and Apache can do it.